Overlay GPS fix data over JPEG Image
I want overlay GPS Fix data in the form of NMEA data on an image I have.
I could use Google Earth but the GPS Fix data are close, therefore I want a zoomed in image showing the fixes.
Going an internet search, I came across the tool called BPSBabel. Using this tool, I was able to convert NMEA data into GPX file format that I can import into QGIS software.
I was able to import the image but I cannot overlay the Fix points onto the JPEG file.
Could someone suggest the best way to achieve this?
I read about georeferenced image. How could I get a georeferenced image?

Both georeferencing (image) and and gps fix (points) need to be in the same coordinate system see https://youtu.be/XV62QEk0Cxg?si=Bc69JocBSljGvCMC&t=114 for an example.
